# flutter convert text field code in class and constructor for state less widget

Tags: flutter, class, textfield

I am new to flutter.
I want to convert Text Field widget in
class as like below syntax.

**class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {**

for below code.
Thanks in advance

```
                TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "enter email",
                      fillColor: Colors.white24,
                      filled: true,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              width: 4)),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid,
                              width: 4)),
                    )),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do but if I've understood your question you want to put the default Material `TextField` into your own custom widget called `MyTextField`. You can do this by putting your existing code inside the `build` method of `MyTextField` like below:

```dart
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "enter email",
        fillColor: Colors.white24,
        filled: true,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.blue, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.white, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to add parameters like a changable value for the hint text you can do so like below:

```dart
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  final InputBorder enabledBorder;

  MyTextField({this.hint, this.enabledBorder});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: hint,
        fillColor: Colors.white24,
        filled: true,
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
                color: Colors.blue, style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 4)),
        enabledBorder: enabledBorder,
    );
  }
}
```

and then you can use the widget like:

```dart
MyTextField(
  hint: "enter email",
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white,
      style: BorderStyle.solid,
      width: 4,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Yes. perfect.  I want enabledborder  method changeable.  how can it can be done as like your hint syntax.

Comment: In the same way :). Create a new variable called enabledBorder for your `MyTextField` widget and then pass in the type of enabledBorder you want. I've updated my answer to show you for `enabledBorder`, you can do the same thing for any parameter inside your widget. Please upvote and accept my answer if it's the one you're looking for.